# Is there a clean way to remove characters (not actual keys) from an xml?

Tags: karate

I have been utilizing set and remove to manipulate my xmls before sending it for an API call. However, those only take care of keys/elements and not characters.

I want to achieve the following:

```
<abc>
123
</abc>

I want to remove the opening bracket for "abc" (instead of '<abc>', I want 'abc>') in order to create a "malformed xml" and make sure my API call fails and returns the appropriate response.
```

Any clean way to do that natively in Karate?

Comment: The linked duplicate question is not what I was going for. I know how set and remove work with respect to xml manipulation. However, my question was sort of negative testing of a "malformed xml" where one of the elements is missing a closing bracket. I suspect I will just send the request in as string. Thank you for the help, as always!